# Pure JQuery based range slider which doesn't use jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

Does anyone know a good, independent jQuery range slider plugin that doesn't rely on jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you link to LimeWire?

Anyway,
Check out Flowplayer's [jQuery tools rangeinput](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/index.html). It's all sorts if awesome and super tiny.